# How do I group on a field, while ignoring duplicates from another field?

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I have some data for visitors to my site and want to figure out the number of unique vistors, and the group on some other data.

Sample Data:

```
{
    _id: 1,
    date: "some date",
    pageVisited: "pageName",
    ipAddr:  111.111.111.111
}
```

My pipeline so far:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
    {//Something here to remove any duplicates from ipAddr
    {$group: {
            _id: "$pageVisited",
            count: {$sum: 1}
        }}
])
```

So, I want to eliminate any duplicate IP addresses to get unique visitors to the site in case some people visited multiple times.  It's highly unlikely that any visitors visited more than one page, so I am willing to ignore that problem.  How can I remove duplicates in my query?

Comment: $group by the IP address first?

Comment: When I group by IP first, I lose the pageVisited.  How can I maintain that for the next $group?

Comment: you can group by both like this `_id: { pageVisited: "$pageVisited", ipAddr: "$ipAddr" },`

Comment: Great, that works perfectly, thanks for the help.  If you want to submit it as an answer then I'll accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way for me would be to use [$addToSet](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/addToSet/) operator in the group to first get a `set` of the ip's like so:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $group: {
      _id: "$pageVisited",
      ids: {
        "$addToSet": "$ipAddr"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $project: {
      _id: 1,
      count: {
        $size: "$ids"
      }
    }
  }
])
```

[Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/gyh3ib-7UfA)